# How to correctly update column of filtered dataframe in pandas avoiding chained indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a pandas dataframe. The first thing is to filter and create a new dataframe`(df1)` from the original dataframe`(df)` based on number that i specify in `num_posts column` and `user column is user1`, then next step is to update the `num_posts` to another number, and finalize by updating `df` from `df1`.

The original df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_posts': [4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 14],
                   'date': ['2020-08-09', '2020-08-25', 
                            '2020-09-05', '2020-09-12', 
                            '2020-09-29', '2020-10-15'],
                  'user': ['user1', 'user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user4']})


# The new filtered df1
# filter posts that equal 4 and user is user1
df1 = df.loc[(df['num_posts'] == 4) & (df['user'] == 'user1')]
df1

# overwrite the num_posts column with 10
for i in df1.index:
    df1.loc[i, 'num_posts'] = 10

# Updating the original dataframe df with df1
df.update(df1)
df
```

When i run my code i get the following warning displayed.

```
C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1817: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  self._setitem_single_column(loc, value, pi)
```

On opening the link in the warning message, i'm redirected to pandas official website, the issue seems to be chained indexing. I need assistance to know how to get rid of it and avoid it on successive filtering of the same original dataframe df.

Comment: Why doesn't this work for your case?  `df.loc[df['num_posts'] == 4, 'num_posts'] = 10`   No loops needed.

Comment: Maybe `df.replace({'num_posts': {4: 10}}, inplace=True)` would be even more fluent in this particular example. i.e. replace 4 with 10.

Comment: Hi sir, you  have missed it. First is to update `num_posts` column  in `df1` aka filtered dataframe, then update the original dataframe `df` from `df1`

Comment: Have tried this, however i'm getting the same error warning message `df1.loc[df1['num_posts'] == 4, 'num_posts'] = 10`

Comment: The requirement is to filter all rows that have num of posts equal 4, i removed some columns in the orginal dataframe that will be useful when i filter the dataframe. The first thing after i filter the dataframe to send email, then set num of post to another number.

Comment: Maybe update the question so that it explains more about what you need? At the moment all the code can be replaced by `df.loc[df['num_posts'] == 4, 'num_posts'] = 10`.

Comment: @creanion have already updated the question, if i apply the solution you have shared, it will also modify num_posts for `user3` in the original dataframe which is not intended.

Comment: Probably, the warning comes out due to the fact that the values ​​are changed in the copy, which can be reflected in the original. But, this doesn't happen. Therefore, I suggested using copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps, try this:

```
#df1 = df.loc[(df['num_posts'] == 4)].copy()
df1 = df.loc[(df['num_posts'] == 4) & (df['user'] == 'user1')].copy()
```

description [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)

Output

```
   num_posts        date   user
0       10.0  2020-08-09  user1
1       10.0  2020-08-25  user1
2        3.0  2020-09-05  user2
3        4.0  2020-09-12  user3
4        1.0  2020-09-29  user4
5       14.0  2020-10-15  user4
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you for solution, however it updates num_posts column in the filtered dataframe as expected, and fails to update num_posts in the original dataframe. Upon running `df.update(df1) df` i get the orginal dataframe back, with num_posts column with 4 instead of 10.

Comment: @Bernietechy what is wrong in output?

Comment: Your `copy` is a good.

Comment: Creanion the copy works without the warning. I'm grateful for the contribution. Thank you @inquirer, have noticed an issue in other part of code that causing the original df not to  be updated on num_posts column, i will ask in another thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it like this.

This is intentionally written used the "extract part, modify, write back" strategy that the question intends.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_posts': [4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 14],
                   'date': ['2020-08-09', '2020-08-25', 
                            '2020-09-05', '2020-09-12', 
                            '2020-09-29', '2020-10-15'],
                  'user': ['user1', 'user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', 'user4']})


# The new filtered df1
# filter posts that equal 4 and user is user1
df1 = df.loc[(df['num_posts'] == 4) & (df['user'] == 'user1')].copy()
df1

# overwrite the num_posts column with 10 in the filtered part
df1.loc[:, 'num_posts'] = 10


# Updating the original dataframe df with df1
df.loc[df1.index] = df1
df
```

However you can also just work on the filtered part like this:

```py
post_filter = (df['num_posts'] == 4) & (df['user'] == 'user1')

# overwrite num_posts directly in the filtered part
df.loc[post_filter, 'num_posts'] = 10
```